# fetching result using php array_values in different php version

Tags: php

Can anyone explain why the following code works in php5.6, not working in php5.3?

```
array_values(array)[key]
```

or give me some keywords ?
I've googled for that but cannot find any answers.

Comment: Yes, this syntax is not OK in php 5.3. You need do `$temp = array_values(array);` and `$temp[$key];` after

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: It's a language trait that came in 5.4, it's pretty descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called Array Dereferencing. Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];
```